# Specifying thread stack size in pthreads

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I want to increase the stack size of a thread created through pthread_create(). The way to go seems to be

```
int pthread_attr_setstack( pthread_attr_t *attr,
                           void *stackaddr,
                           size_t stacksize );
```

from `pthread.h`.

However, according to multiple online [references](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_attr_setstack.html),

> The stackaddr shall be aligned appropriately to be used as a stack; for example, pthread_attr_setstack() may fail with [EINVAL] if ( stackaddr & 0x7) is not 0.

My question: could someone provide an example of how to perform the alignment? Is it (the alignment) platform or implementation dependent?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Never** use `pthread_attr_setstack`. It has a lot of fatal flaws, the worst of which is that it is impossible to *ever* free or reuse the stack after a thread has been created using it. (POSIX explicitly states that any attempt to do so results in undefined behavior.)

POSIX provides a much better function, `pthread_attr_setstacksize` which allows you to request the stack size you need, but leaves the implementation with the responsibility for allocating and deallocating the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the categorical answer :)

Comment: No problem. :-) Another flaw I failed to mention is that there's no portable way of setting up guard pages with `pthread_attr_setstack`, so stack overflows will lead to memory corruption with likely-dangerous consequences rather than just `SIGSEGV`.

Answer (score 1):

Look into `posix_memalign()`.

It will allocate a memory block of the requested alignment and size.